# mySQL - return 0 as an aggregate result if a field not found

Tags: mysql

If for example I have:

```
CREATE TABLE application (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`month` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`amount` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL)
;
INSERT INTO application 
(`id`, `month`, `amount`)
VALUES 
(1, 'january', 2000.00),
(2, 'february', 1000.00),
(3, 'january', 3000.00),
(4, 'january', 5000.00)
;
```

And then I run the query:

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`) as sum FROM application WHERE month IN ('january', 'february', 'march') GROUP BY `month`;
```

I get the result:

```
  month      sum
___________________
january  | 10000.00
february | 1000.00
```

which is what the query was supposed to do however I'm looking for this result:

```
  month      sum
___________________
january  | 10000.00
february | 1000.00
march    | 0.00
```

how can I achieve this?

if anyone needs clarity don't vote down just ask and I will be more precise if i can.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.mname, SUM(ISNULL(a.`amount`,0)) as sum 
FROM 
(
select 'january' as mname union all
select 'february' as mname union all
select 'march' as mname 
) m LEFT JOIN application a on a.`month` = m.mname 
GROUP BY a.`month`
```